# Script to act as keyboard for android device

Tags: applications, usb, external-keyboard

TLDR: I need to create a keyboard interface to android, does this already exist? or am I going about this the wrong way?

I'm running tests from my computer that require me to interact with an android device. What I would like to do is write an application that runs on my testing computer that can talk to my android devices as a mock keyboard. Right now my testing methods are, my desktop app runs, returns a string of text, **I type string of text into application on android device,** android devices does its thing (posts modified text to cloud datastore), desktop app gets value from datastore, and repeats.

I would really like to take the manual step out of the testing procedure. I had some ideas on how to control the android device's keyboard using an arduino with the keyboard library, but I would think I could do this with a just a usb between the testing computer and android device. I've looked around online but most forms I'm finding are talking about using an android as a keyboard for a pc (which is the opposite of what I need).

Comment: As Android already has resources for [UI testing](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing) you might want to start there. You can also use the `adb` command from a PC to [inject input events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7789826/295004)

Comment: You can simulate text input from a keyboard via [`adb input text "qwerty"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)

Comment: Thanks both of these suggestions work